# How to combine DSolve and FindRoot

Tags: differential-equations

As my differential function is relatively complex I do not want to do the detour of finding an explicit solution via DSolve for it but rather use an FindRoot-like approach by guessing initial starting values.

Following example:

Let `z[t]` be the differential where the start and end values are known:

`z[0]=z0` and `z[tmax]=zend`, but the end time `tmax` is unknown.

The (simplified) differential (where the paths of `l2[t]`and `l3[t]` as well as their end values `l2final` and `l3final` are well-defined) is:

```
DSolve[{z[0] == z0, z[tmax] == zend, z'[t]==f[l20[t],l3[t]],l2[tmax]==l2final, l30[tmax]==l3final}, z[t],t]
```

The only unkown is `tmax`. So I don't want to do the `DSolve` described as I don't care about an explicit solution of z[t]. But I rather want to search for something like:

```
FindRoot[z[t]-zend,{t,0,100}]
```

Does anybody have an idea how to combine both approaches EFFICIENTLY?

Btw: `z[t]` is continously increasing as well as `l2[t]` and `l3[t]`

Answer (score 2):

It helps to give code that can reproduce you're problem, but here's a guess at what you're after. I removed the conditions `l2[tmax]==l2final, l30[tmax]==l3final` because if `l2` and `l3` are well defined and `tmax` is defined by `z[tmax] == tend`, then `l2final` and `l3final` are determined by the result.

[`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WhenEvent.html) is the way to solve `z[t] == zend`.

```
f[x_, y_] := x + y^2/4;
l20[t_] := t + Cos[4 t]^2; l3[t_] := 2 t + Sin[2 t];
z0 = 10.;
zend = 100.;
sol = First @ NDSolve[{z[0] == z0, z'[t] == f[l20[t], l3[t]]
                    WhenEvent[z[t] == zend, tmax = t; "StopIntegration"]}, 
        z[t], {t, 0, Infinity}]

tmax

(*
   InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,1.76425}},<>]
   5.97248
*)

Plot[sol[t], Evaluate[{t, Sequence @@ First@sol["Domain"]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]